# double integral over unbounded region?

Tags: probability, statistics, multivariable-calculus

I've looked through a few calculus textbooks and I'm not finding much about how to reduce double integrals over unbounded regions to iterated integrals. Usually double integrals over bounded regions are discussed and categorized as either "type 1" or "type 2", and from there we have some version of Fubini's Theorem which lets us do iterated integration.

Here is an example appearing in a book on statistics:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)
=
\begin{cases}
2e^{-x-y} & 0<x<y\\
0 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}$

I have to find $P(Y<3X)$. I believe this is just the double integral over the region between the lines $y=x$ and $y=3x$ in the first quadrant. Is there a definition or theorem that lets me make the reduction to iterated integration?

Comment: Without fancy stuff, just do the (Riemann) integral over larger and larger rectangles $[0,R]\times [0,3R]$.

Answer (score 1):

The [Fubini-Tonelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#The_Fubini.E2.80.93Tonelli_theorem) implies that since your $f(x,y)$ is non-negative and integrable, you can evaluate the double integral in any way. For example:

$$\int_{0}^\infty\int_{y/3}^\infty f(x,y)dxdy.$$

To be clear, you'll show that $f(x,y)$ is integrable by deducing the above integral is finite, after which the Fubini-Tonelli theorem will imply that any order of evaluation of the above integral will gave the same answer.